# Show that if the Euler Totient value for $n$ is equal to $n-1$, then $n$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory

As the title indicates, I want to show that if $\varphi(n)=n-1$, then $n$ is prime. Also, $n$ is a positive integer.

Here is what I have so far:

Consider that $n$ has some prime factorization, so that $\varphi(n)=\varphi(p_{1}^{x_{1}}\cdot p_{2}^{x_{2}} \cdot\cdot\cdot p_{r}^{x_{r}})$ where $p_{r}$ is a unique prime number. And, since each $p_{i}$ is relatively prime to every other $p_{i}$, we invoke a prior theorem so that $\varphi(p_{1}^{x_{1}}\cdot p_{2}^{x_{2}} \cdot\cdot\cdot p_{r}^{x_{r}})=\varphi(p_{1}^{x_{1}})\cdot \varphi(p_{2}^{x_{2}}) \cdot\cdot\cdot \varphi(p_{r}^{x_{r}})=(p_{1}^{x_{1}}-p_{1}^{x_{1}-1})(p_{2}^{x_{2}}-p_{2}^{x_{2}-1})\cdot\cdot\cdot(p_{r}^{x_{r}}-p_{r}^{x_{r}-1})$.

...and I was going to prove something about this thing equaling (n-1), but it seems not helpful. Is there another approach that may be better?

Comment: It actually follows directly from the definition. If $\phi(n)=n-1$, then $1,2,3,..,n-1$ are all relatively prime to $n$. Can $n$ be composite?

Comment: We have not learned in class yet about quotient groups, and no algebra background is required for the class.  I think we should either use this formula I described above, or else there is another formula where $\varphi(p_{1}^{x_{1}}\cdot p_{2}^{x_{2}} \cdot\cdot\cdot p_{r}^{x_{r}})=n(1-\frac{1}{p_{1}})(1-\frac{1}{p_{2}})\cdot\cdot\cdot(1-\frac{1}{p_{r}})$ which I am also trying to see is helpful or not. (Or, any other properties of algebra and basic number theory).

Comment: Yeah, updated my comment to just use the definition of $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes it makes sense. Those factors are all prime in that case (if any are composite, then they would share a factor with some lesser factor...in fact, it would be equal to one of the smaller factors, and then the n-1 integers would not all be relatively prime after all). So, they are all prime. And, that's the whole proof. Thank you! I am good at making things more complicated than needed :)